# Will my Pokémon follow me from Android to iOS?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am moving from my Samsung Android phone to an iPhone. Can I open my Pokémon account on an iPhone if it was created on Android with my Google Account?

Comment: Yes - use the same Google account. All the player information is stored on their servers, so if you sign in with the same Google account, all your information will be restored.

Comment: Why is this being down voted so hard?

Comment: As I don't find any duplicate (or any other reason to downvote), I'm upvoting this post +1

Comment: @SysDragon If you're upvoting for any other reason than the post itself, you're doing it wrong.  Votes are for your judgement of the post itself, not a response of how others have voted.

Comment: @Frank I don't understand you. Did I say otherwise? I was going to upvote, but the post had -3 score and I guessed there was a reason. Since I didn't manage to find it, I just upvoted as intended

Comment: @SysDragon The way you worded your comment made it sound like you were voting to counteract other votes.  There seems to be no other reason to comment like you did.

Comment: @Frank Those are your assumptions. Sorry that I didn't worded myself good enough but as I said, your assumptions are not what I meant. Next time maybe you can try to ask before assuming things, and I'll try to word myself better

Answer (score 5):

Yes, all account information is stored on Niantic's servers. Just log in with the Google Account you played with before and all your game data (items, pokémon, achievements, etc) will still be there.